# Standard Normal Variable : Existence and uniqueness

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Problem: Prove that $\forall$ $\alpha \in (0,1)$, there exists a unique $z_\alpha$ such that $P(Z>z_\alpha)=\alpha$ where $Z$ is a standard normal r.v.

So, $P(Z>z_\alpha) = \int_{z_\alpha}^\infty f_x dx$ where $f_x$ is the pdf of a standard r.v.How do I procced to show existence and uniqueness?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the cdf of the standard normal
$$
P(Z\leq z)= F(z)=\int_{-\infty}^z f(t)\,dt
$$
where $f$ is the pdf of a standard normal. We claim that $F:\mathbb{R}\to (0,1)$ is a bijection. Indeed, first note that $\lim_{t\to -\infty} F(t)=0$ and $\lim_{t\to \infty} F(t)=1$. Since $F$ is continuous, the intermediate value theorem implies that $F$ is surjective. Next because $F'(z)=f(z)>0$, it follows that $F$ is strictly increasing and hence injectivve.

Given $\alpha\in (0,1)$, 
$$
P(Z>z_\alpha)=\alpha\iff 1-\alpha=F(z_\alpha)
$$ 
from which the result follows from the previous paragraph.

Comment: How does uniqueness follow? I am sorry I didn't get that.

Comment: $F$ is a bijection from $\mathbb{R}$ to $(0,1)$.